# Let f be a positive integer be define recursively by $f(1)=1$ and $f(n+1)=\sqrt{2+f(n)}$ for all integers n. Prove that $f(n) = (2^n)-1$.

Tags: induction

Let f: be a positive integer defined recursively by $f(1)=1$ and $f(n+1)=\sqrt{2+f(n)}$ for all integers n. Prove that $f(n)<2$.

I am supposed to prove this by using proof of induction. I've tested the base case of 1, and I've let $P(n)$ be the statement that $f(n)<2$. I'm not sure how to go about the rest. I can't seem to prove that it is true for the case of $n+1$.

Comment: See this closely related [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/504443/462) for a standard approach to these problems.

Comment: Wrong title. $ $

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\sqrt{2+2}=2$. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$