# clarification on simplifying limits

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I was working on the same question listed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504427/prove-sqrts-n1-frac121-sqrt5?rq=1) and  came up with the follwing proof with help of answers on that and other questions.

$\lim s_n$ converges so let $\lim s_n =s$.

Now $s_{n+1}= \sqrt{s_n+1}$ thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{s_n +1}$.

From here we get $s=\sqrt{s+1}$.

Simplifying gives: $s^2-s-1$. We do the quadratic formula and go without the extraneous solution and end up with $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Now I get lost from the limits to plugging in s? I was using the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491709/monotone-and-bounded-sequences-proof/491747#491747) to help with my thought process. Why can we "substitute" $s$?

Answer (score 1):

That is because the square root function is continuous, so 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl(\sqrt{s_{n}+1}\,\bigr)=\sqrt{\lim_{n\to\infty}(s_n+1)}=\sqrt{(\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n)+1}.$$